# When .fileImporter is presented the Xcode console shows: "Unknown client: App Name"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, nsfilemanager

I am writing my first **SwiftUI app** that uses the `FileManager` (via `.fileImporter`) to read data from a saved text (`.csv`) file.

Although everything seems to be working OK, the Xcode console displays the following every time the code is invoked:

#### `Unknown client: MyApp Name`

Perhaps worthy to note…

1. My app name **is** two words long, separated by a space.
2. My app name **does** contain a `ō` character.

I hate ignoring errors/warnings AND I'd rather have my app be a KNOWN Client.

Could I be missing something in my code or in my `info.plist` that informs FileManager of my app's existence?

#### Here is my code:

```swift
.fileImporter(isPresented: $isShowing, allowedContentTypes: [.item], allowsMultipleSelection: false, onCompletion: { results in

// yada yada yada

}
```